# What is the importance of properties in MVC Model Binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have an Ajax Query that does the following:

```
var dataToSend = {
    userValueExample: {
        name: 'Rintu', email: 'Rintu@gmialsfdfs.com'
    }
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/Transactions/TestMethod',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

In the c# classes, I have the following:

```
public class UserTest {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public void TestMethod(UserTest userValueExample) {
    // Do whatever. Used a breakpoint to see values.
}
```

Now, the above would work perfectly but it took me ages to realize that the {get;set;} is required for MVC model binding to work properly..

Prior to this, I use fields:

```
public class UserTest {
    public string name;
    public string email;
}
```

This fails for some unknown reason and when the breakpoint hits, the values for 'userValueExample' in the `TestMethod()` is of a default property initialization.

Why is a property important in this case and why is it required for the ModelBinding to work properly?

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` first initializes your model (using `Activator.CreateInstance()`) and then it read the posted values and **sets** the values of the properties. Without a setter, it cannot set the value.

Comment: A field doesn't need a setter, right? @StephenMuecke They could enumerate over fields too.

Comment: They could. They also could translate them, or make coffee. Point being that the standards established are making properties mandatory and the MVC field decided to follow them - so they ignore fields. Talking about what is possible is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't entirely agree @TomTom. I can be useful to understand decisions made by the language team. That might help us do our jobs better.

Comment: That is not the point. You start speculating what is possible. That is opinionated and not welcome here. Then you go on talking about intention, which is speculation and again opinionated.

Comment: You can download the code and see it is possible. It just isn't implemented.

Comment: @PatrickHofman In the DefaultModelBinder.cs file, which area is the property being set? I'm trying to understand what gets called when the values are being set by MVC?

Comment: Yes, it is in [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs#L196). They could extend that to allow fields too.

Comment: @SamuelTambunan, You can see the [DefaultModelBinder source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it doesn't matter that much, basically it is a design decision from the CLR team to add more value and logic to properties over fields.

As [a member of the VB team](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja/) says:

> 4. A lot of the .NET databinding infrastructure binds to properties but not fields
>
>    I’ve heard arguments on both sides as to whether or not that’s a good thing, but the reality is that’s the way it works right now.